# php mongodb find distinct val return multiple parameters

Tags: php, mongodb, distinct

My documents look like this:

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => ...
)
[homeId] => 39898
[sensor] => bopt
[date] => MongoDate Object (
    [sec] => 1376258370
    [usec] => 0
)
[val] => 5687
```

and I want to query 'date.sec','sensor','homeId' and 'val'.
The thing is, I want the 'val' to be DISTINCT

```
$this->condition = array('homeId' => (int)$this->homeId, 'date' => array('$gte' => new MongoDate($this->fromDate), '$lt' => new MongoDate($this->toDate)), 'sensor' => $this->sensor);
$cursor = $this->collection->distinct('val',$this->condition);
```

How can I get it to return not only the 'val' but all the fields?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use the `$group` operator in the aggregation framework instead

Comment: thank you! can you give an example?

Comment: Google really comes in handy here, this is an extremely common question, however: `$this->collection->aggregate(array(array('$match'=>array('homeId' => (int)$this->homeId, 'date' => array('$gte' => new MongoDate($this->fromDate), '$lt' => new MongoDate($this->toDate)), 'sensor' => $this->sensor)),array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'$val', 'homeId'=>array('$max'=>'$homeId') // Copy for all fields ))))`

Comment: thank you! upgraded 2.0.0 -> 2.1.+ needed!